# SDL Web8 Context Menu not working in firefox version 45.4.0

Tags: web8

I try to open the existing schema using Firefox version 45.4.0. Context Menu not working for me. any one have idea about this issue.[image]

Comment: try http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-B0393E1F-2F38-4CC0-841C-44D78AAE0B33 point:13 especially

Comment: Raj, Thanks for info. it`s looks working fine after setup all Firefox steps.

Comment: moved my comment to answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your browser properly using link below.

http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-B0393E1F-2F38-4CC0-841C-44D78AAE0B33

You can configure Firefox using Point No 13 and other browser as well if required.